# Multiple inheritance - wrong overload selected

Tags: perl, oop, overloading, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying out multiple inheritance and would like to get the hang of it without using packages like `Moose` to sort out the issue behind the scenes.

I have two base classes, `Left` and `Right`, in a "broken" diamond:

```
Left  Right
   \   /
   Multi
```

They both implement an `overload` for `""`. When calling a method, below named `perform`, in any of the base classes, those methods are supposed to use this overload to print a representation of that part of the object. `Multi` implements `perform` as so:

```
sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->Left::perform;
    $self->Right::perform;
}
```

What happens is that both base classes `perform` methods are called as they are supposed to, but when those methods call any other methods (like the `""` overload) it'll always be the one in `Left`. However, if an instance of `Right` is created separately (not as a part of `Multi`) it'll call the correct method.

- I wonder how to make a method in this scenario select its own package's methods over its left-most sibling base class' methods?

Here's what I've tried (in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) v5.26.1 and v5.32.1):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package Left; #----------------------------------------------------------------

sub new {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    return $self->_init(@args);
}

sub _init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{_leftval} = shift;
    return $self;
}

sub value { shift->{_leftval}; }

use overload '""' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    'Left(' . $self->value . ')';
};

sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    print '# LEFT ' . $self . "\n";
}

package Right; #---------------------------------------------------------------

sub new {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    return $self->_init(@args);
}

sub _init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{_rightval} = shift;
    return $self;
}

sub value { shift->{_rightval}; }

use overload '""' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    'Right(' . $self->value . ')';
};

sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    print '# RIGHT ' . $self . "\n";
}

package Multi; #---------------------------------------------------------------
use parent -norequire, 'Left', 'Right' ;

sub new {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    return $self->_init(@args);
}

sub _init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->Left::_init(shift);
    $self->Right::_init(shift);
    return $self;
}

sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->Left::perform;
    $self->Right::perform;
}

package main; #----------------------------------------------------------------

my $l = Left->new("a Left");
my $r = Right->new("a Right");
my $m = Multi->new("lEfT", "rIgHt");

$l->perform;
$r->perform;
print "---- and now a Multi ----\n";
$m->perform;
```

Expected output:

```
# LEFT Left(a Left)
# RIGHT Right(a Right)
---- and now a Multi ----
# LEFT Left(lEfT)
# RIGHT Right(rIgHt)
```

Actual output (note the last line):

```
# LEFT Left(a Left)
# RIGHT Right(a Right)
---- and now a Multi ----
# LEFT Left(lEfT)
# RIGHT Left(lEfT)
```

Comment: *"I wonder how to make a method in this scenario select its own package's methods"* : What is wrong with simply using `$self->{_rightval}` instead of `$self->value` in the overload sub?

Comment: See also [mro](https://perldoc.perl.org/mro)

Comment: @HåkonHægland Nothing really, but that doesn't help. It's the `Left` `""` overload that's being called. I will check that MRO out to see if I can figure out _how_ it does what it does. It solves the "full" diamond problem so perhaps there are some hints in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A virtual method is resolved based on the object's class, not the caller's namespace/package/class.

In Perl, whether a method is virtual or not isn't an intrinsic property. It depends on how it's called.

```perl
$o->method   # Virtual method
```

Avoiding this require specifying the class

```perl
$o->Class::method
```

---

You don't want a virtual method call, so you'll need to change how you call the method.

```perl
package Left;

use overload '""' => \&to_string;

sub to_string {
    my $self = shift;
    'Left(' . $self->value . ')';
}

sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    print '# LEFT ' . $self->Left::to_string() . "\n";
}
```

---

Except that's all wrong. If it was one method, this would make sense. But we're talking about every method. This is the air raid siren of red flags.

What we want here is composition, not inheritance. Multi IS A Left and IS A Right isn't correct. Rather, Multi HAS A Left and HAS A Right.

```perl
package Multi; #---------------------------------------------------------------
use parent -norequire, 'Left', 'Right' ;

sub new {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    return $self->_init(@args);
}

sub _init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{ left  } = Left ->new(shift);
    $self->{ right } = Right->new(shift);
    return $self;
}

sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{ left  }->perform;
    $self->{ right }->perform;
}
```

Comment: This would work but makes it really cumbersome since I would need to be explicit _everywhere_. `$self->value` in my stripped down example would also need to be called with `$self->Class::value` or else it'd still print the "left" value for the "right" object etc. Well, this is certainly an option that doesn't cast blessing spells all over (which also makes it necessary to implement every virtual method in the most derived class to not leave objects ruined).

Comment: Re "*also need to be called with $self->Class::value*", You only said the override in the question. This info changes everything. You are misusing inheritance.  You should be using containership. Wrong: Multi IS A Left and IS A Right. Right: Multi HAS A Left and HAS A Right.

Comment: I did say "_any other_" and "_like the_"  in "_when those methods call any other methods (like the `""` overload)_"  - but I get your point. Composition is the answer. Put that in the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder how to make a method in this scenario select its own package's methods

Does it help to rebless `$self` like this:

```
package Right;

# [...]

sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    if (ref $self ne "Right") {
        bless $self, "Right";
    }
    print '# RIGHT ' . $self . "\n";
}
```

Comment: It looked like it could work but it seems to break the chain. The next call to `$m->perform` goes directly to `Right::perform`. Not even `Multi::perform` is invoked. You may be on to something though so it's good food for thought.

Comment: If I do this in both `Left` and `Right` and rebless in `Multi::perform` _after_ having called `Left::perform` and `Right::perform` - it works. I'll also need to make sure this is done in _all_ methods in all classes - but I'll accept this answer if nothing quite as complicated pops up.

Answer (score 1):

This is building on [Håkon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70111540/7582247). `bless $self, 'Right'` in `Right::perform` effectively seems to break the inheritance. A second call to `$m->perform` directly calls `Right::perform` - `Multi::perform` isn't even invoked.

As a workaround to this, I added a blessing context class which blesses upon creation *and* on destruction. I'll have to create one of these contexts in all methods potentially calling any method in another package.

```
package Reblesser; #-----------------------------------------------------------

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless {
        object => shift,
        class => shift
    }, $class;
    $self->rebless;
    $self;
}

sub rebless {
    my $self = shift;
    bless $self->{object}, $self->{class} if(ref $self->{object} ne $self->{class});
}

sub DESTROY {
    shift->rebless;
}
```

Now `Left::perform` becomes:

```
sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    my $ctx = Reblesser->new($self, __PACKAGE__);
    print '# LEFT ' . $self . "\n";
}
```

`Right::perform`:

```
sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    my $ctx = Reblesser->new($self, __PACKAGE__);
    print '# RIGHT ' . $self . "\n";
}
```

`Multi::perform`:

```
sub perform {
    my $self = shift;
    my $ctx = Reblesser->new($self, __PACKAGE__);
    $self->Left::perform;
    $self->Right::perform;
}
```

Output (even with multiple `$m->perform` calls):

```
# LEFT Left(a Left)
# RIGHT Right(a Right)
---- and now a Multi ----
# LEFT Left(lEfT)
# RIGHT Right(rIgHt)
```